# Why is this deleted move constructor accepted by the compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

In the following code example, I have no particular reason to delete the move constructor, but I don't understand why it compiles (`x` is an object that prints whether it is moved or copied).

```
class foo {
    X x;

public:
    foo()=default;
    foo(const foo &)=default;
    foo(foo &&)=delete;
};

int main()
{
    vector<foo> v;
    foo a;

    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(a);
}
```

The second time `push_back` is called on the `std::vector`, it relocates the already existing object, usually with a move operation. With the `foo` move constructor declared 'default', I can see this happen.

However, when the move constructor is explicitly deleted, I'd expect compilation to fail since it is still available for overload, but deleted.
It does compile and the vector reallocation uses the copy constructor.

What is happening here ?

Comment: None of your code needs the move constructor as the copy constructor is already sufficient, so what?

Comment: If move is not possible/desirable, `vector` will be fall back on the copy constructor.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand that happens when the move constructor is not declared.. But when explicitly deleted, it is still available for overloads, but no definition exists

Comment: This is undefined behavior. GCC 9 indeed [rejects the code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7XC0N1v1oSWZRFtP).

Comment: @xskxzr Interesting, the reason it fails is indeed the deleted move operation.. This is what I was expecting to happen on gcc 8.2

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You don't understand the question.. Saying that a move constructor is not needed in a question that is about a move constructor makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector::resize()` will move if it can, and copy if it must.  This is extremely useful, as not all copyable types are movable. Keep in mind in c++ that objects are value types, not reference types.

Comment: I understand that not all copyable types are movable, but that is usually achieved by not declaring a move operation. When move operations are explicitly deleted, they can still be picked by overload resolution (and then fail to compile)

Comment: @Tootsie And `std::vector` can detect that moving is deleted without failing to compile, using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), and fall back to copying.

Comment: And in addition to Daniel H's comment, this detecting is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the copy constructor here aren't you? `foo(const foo &)`. Keep in mind in c++ that objects are value types, not reference types.

Answer (score -1):

To move `a` into the vector you have to make it a r-value, that is, to use `std::move(a)` instead of just `a`.
I believe if you do that your code will error on the deleted move ctor.

Comment: the question is about internal relocation that sometimes happens when `push_back` is called. This internal relocation will move or copy all the elements currently in the vector.